# Opt-Out using queueMO API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I am trying to opt-out of SMS using QueueMO API but getting error. Below is the request and response. Any idea what could be going wrong? Is there any other way to opt-out using REST API? Thanks in Advance.

endpoint - https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/queueMO
Method - POST

Request :

```json
    {
      "mobileNumbers": [
        "12405517333"
      ],
      "shortCode": "88769",
      "messageText": "STOP"
    }
```

Response :

```json
    {
        "errors": [
            "Client, ShortCode, Keyword combination is invalid."
        ]
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you don't have the preceding "1" on the mobile number?  Same thing?

Comment: yes same thing.

Comment: Do you have any Text Response or Mobile Opt-In messages set up for that particular short code?

Comment: Please find the Summary below

TEMPLATE TYPE
Mobile Opt-In
SHORT/LONG CODE
88769
KEYWORD
MOZIDO_TEST
CAMPAIGN ASSOCIATIONS
--
Messages

EXTERNAL SOURCE
Text 'MOZIDO_TEST'  to 88769.

SUBSCRIPTION OPTIONS
Double Opt-in

OUTBOUND RESPONSE
Thanks for subscribing! Please respond with y to confirm your subscription.

OUTBOUND CONFIRMATION
Thanks for subscribing! You will receive approx 20 message(s) per Week.

StartSaturday, August 09, 2014 2:05 PM
EndNever
Time Zone(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada) *
ERROR RESPONSE
Sorry, there was an error. Please try again.

Comment: same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a placeholder/sample shortcode; assuming you are swapping this out when making the call, if this is a new shortcode that has not completed carrier review, it is likely the STOP keyword is not configured in the UI.